# Set-cookie header is missing from Spring Security authentication response

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I'm creating a Spring Boot application, and planning to perform authentication via api request and respond sessionId.

WebSecurityConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity, authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            authorizeHttpRequests {
                authorize("/api/login", permitAll)
                authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
                HttpMethod.PUT
                HttpMethod.DELETE
            }
            csrf { disable() }
        }

        http.addFilter(ApiUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager))
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder(8)
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager {
        return authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager
    }
}
```

UserDetailServiceImpl.kt

```
@Service
@Transactional
class UserDetailServiceImpl(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
) : UserDetailsService {
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): UserDetails {
        // Created custom UserRepository to fetch user data from database
        val loginUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
            ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException("User not found")

        return LoginUserDetails(loginUser)
    }
}
```

ApiUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.kt

```
data class LoginRequestParams(
    val username: String,
    val password: String,
)

class ApiUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager) :
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager) {
        private val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

        init {
            setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login", "POST"))

            this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler { _, response, _ ->
                response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
            }
            this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler { _, response, _ ->
                response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
            }
        }

        override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): Authentication {
            val loginRequestParams = objectMapper.readValue(request.inputStream, LoginRequestParams::class.java)
            val authenticationToken =
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequestParams.username, loginRequestParams.password)
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken)
        }
    }
```

Now login request gets 200 correctly, but no `set-cookie` header is returned, so I can't keep login state.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "lipsum", "password": "example"}' http://localhost:8080/api/login -i -c cookie.txt
HTTP/1.1 200
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2023 09:29:51 GMT
```

I think Spring Security generates `jsessionid` automatically and I'd like to use it, but is there any more setting required?

Comment: why are you writing custom security as that is bad practice and not using the built in features of spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case is to perform authentication via REST API, and in such cases I need to explicitly save user information using `SecurityContextRepository`.
https://spring.pleiades.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/#publish-authentication-manager-bean

And also as Toerktumlare says, I quit custom filter and instead use another controller, by adding `AuthenticationManager` bean to configuration.

WebSecurityConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity, authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            authorizeHttpRequests {
                authorize("/api/login", permitAll)
                authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
                HttpMethod.PUT
                HttpMethod.DELETE
            }
            csrf { disable() }
        }

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder(8)
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(
        userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
        passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    ): AuthenticationManager {
        val authenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)

        return ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)
    }
}
```

LoginController.kt

```
data class LoginRequestParams(
    val username: String,
    val password: String,
)

@RestController
class LoginController(private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager) {
    private val securityContextHolderStrategy = SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy()
    private val securityContextRepository: SecurityContextRepository = HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()

    @PostMapping("/api/login")
    fun login(
        @RequestBody loginRequestParams: LoginRequestParams,
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
    ) {
        val authenticationToken =
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequestParams.username, loginRequestParams.password)
        val authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken)

        val securityContext = securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext()
        securityContext.authentication = authentication
        securityContextHolderStrategy.context = securityContext
        securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response)
    }
}
```

`UserDetailServiceImpl.kt` is same, and  `ApiUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.kt` is removed.

Now server responds `Set-Cookie` header.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "lipsum", "password": "example"}' http://localhost:8080/api/login -i -c cookie.txt
HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=<cookie value>; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 25 Nov 2023 10:45:44 GMT
```